# Order of Query which includes correlated subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following query where one of the JOIN's relies on a Subquery.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
JOIN C ON A.id = C.id
    AND A.someColumn IN (
        SELECT C.someColumn
        FROM C
        WHERE C.anotherColumn = B.anotherColumn
        );
```

Now if I modify this query so it remains the same except the JOIN order is swapped to B C A, will it still be equivalent to the original query?
Are the outer queries executed first and then the subquery?

Comment: The order of inner joins doesn't matter.

Comment: Note: you use the correlation name `C` twice. Note2: use an `EXISTS(...)` construct instead of an `IN(...)` construct.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, please look at edit (query 2). Are the joins with NO correlated subquery executed first, and then C with subquery?

Comment: No. The second query is not valid. You reference table A before you have joined to it (`FROM B JOIN C ON A.id = C.id`). You could always try both your queries and see if they both run, if they do, check the execution plans to see if they are the same.

Comment: Have you tried running the queries and looking at the actual execution plans? That should answer the question definitively.